# How can I use backreferences to add (not change) strings in the same line with BSD sed?

Tags: recursion, sed, freebsd

To make recurring tasks easier, I like to code shell scripts which (mostly) perform them for me. One of my latest scripts is for creating *ed2k* links with included *http* download URLs.

One example of what I want to achieve: Given that I want to download a specified version of Notepad++ to my "Shared" folder, I just type:

`./dl-notepadpp.sh 6.0.0`

I made it to the point where it downloads all files and passes them to the `alcc` command; which, however, prints plain *ed2k* links without any references.

I basically need a piped `sed` command which turns the `alcc` output

`ed2k://|file|npp.6.0.0.bin.7z|7631311|8b8298915a2670c3f11416ba95f78a88|/`

into

`ed2k://|file|npp.6.0.0.bin.7z|7631311|8b8298915a2670c3f11416ba95f78a88|s=http://download.tuxfamily.org/notepadplus/6.0.0/npp.6.0.0.bin.7z|/`

automatically.

(Of course I don't just want N++ and not just one file, so, technically, I need a `sed` command to add "s=http..." with a file name from an earlier part of the line.)

I tried using `$1` in the replacement string for `sed` which doesn't work.

Any clues?

Comment: You'd use `\1` in `sed` in the replacement side to reference the first remembered sub-pattern.  (`$1` is used in Perl.)  I'm not clear where the `http` part of the information comes from; it certainly isn't specified in the question.  You might want to use a character other than `/` for the `s///` command (for example: `s%%%` using `%` instead of `/`).

Comment: The `http` part varies, depending on the file. I need to hardcode that per script, but still need to use the version number from the file. I thought $1 would be the script parameter. - Well, thanks, I'll fiddle with that.

Comment: Hold on; it depends what we're talking about (I may have misunderstood what you're after).  If it is the version number from the command line, that is `$1` as with any shell.  The main thing to remember is that if you write the `sed` script in single quotes (usually a good idea), then the shell won't replace `$1` with the argument to the script.  You should show your best shot at it; it will make lots of things clear.  You should also show the error message you're getting, or the result you're getting and why it isn't what you want.

Comment: Ah, so I'll have to use double quotes around the `sed` call? This might explain what I was getting wrong. Double quotes do the trick indeed. :-) Thank you! - Actually, I (also) was after having a part of the `alcc` output attached to the string itself. I guess there's no way to solve that more elegant than with a `sed` call?